# echarts add padding between line chart and y-axis label

Tags: javascript, echarts

I use [echarts plugin](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) to build line chart at a some web pages. It works good but I can't find out inside [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis) how to add padding between line chart and y-axis label and move y-axis label to the center between y-axis split lines?

**Current line echarts plugin instance view:**

[image: Current line echarts plugin instance view]

**Expected line echarts plugin instance view:**

[image: Expected line echarts plugin instance view]

The screenshot above mean that I mentally shifted the graph away from the internal label so that they would not intersect and moved the labels along the y-axis of the game below exactly in the center between the split lines

[image: Mentally shifted the graph away from the internal label so that they would not intersect and moved the labels along the y-axis of the game below exactly in the center between the split lines]

What settings in the plugin do I need to change to achieve the same result as in the screenshot with the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in the different ways, but most of the them are costly to support and harden to implement. It one of safety and ease way but you will need to keep an eye that xAxis have a little bit more points than series data to show gap.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
var option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '10%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    position: 'right',
    axisLabel: {
      inside: true,
      margin: 50,
      fontSize: 18
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    areaStyle: {
      color: 'rgba(104, 216, 214, 0.4)'
    },
    lineStyle: {
      width: 2,
      color: 'rgba(104, 216, 214, 1)'
    },
    data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
  }, ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was helpfull, I add some time padding at x-axis, add it works. The final result you can see at this screenshot: https://img11.lostpic.net/2020/08/24/5469b767264967c1c7ec126a71360044.png

Comment: However, I could not find a solution to offset the labels of the y-axis to the center between splitLines, such a task looks difficult because of the need to recalculate the positioning of labels when scaling the grid of the y-axis. Unless they are somehow rigidly fixed and the label padding is adjusted by eye

Comment: Position for the y Axis.label is not easy, the labels has not tools for it. Take a look on second answer. If this not success then need to make positioning programmatically and redraw on each changes.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
    var seriesData = Array.from({length: 100}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
    var option = {
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
      },
      grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '10%',
        bottom: '15%',
      },
      xAxis: [{
        id: 'xAxis1',
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: Array.from({length: seriesData.length}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)),
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            shadowOffsetX: 60,
          },
        },
      }],
      yAxis: [{
        type: 'value',
        axisLine: { onZero: false },
        position: 'right',
        show: true,
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
          },
        },
        splitLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            shadowOffsetX: 60,
            shadowColor: '#ccc'
          }
        },
        axisLabel: {
          interval: 0,
          inside: true,
          margin: -45,
          fontSize: 16,
          padding: [-50, 0, 0, 0],
          color: 'black',
          showMinLabel: false,
          showMaxLabel: false,
        },
      },{
          type: 'value',
          position: 'right',
          show: true,
          offset: 59,
        }
      ],
  dataZoom: [{
    type: 'inside'
  }, {
    type: 'slider',
    show: true,
    bottom: 0
  }],
  series: [{
    id: 'series1',
    type: 'line',
    yAxisIndex: [0,1],
    lineStyle: {
      width: 1,
    },
    label: {},
    data: seriesData,
  }],
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```